# Equations of motion and infinitesimal canonical transformations

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, time-evolution

Currently, I'm diving into infinitesimal canonical transformations, with a particular focus on using the infinitesimal change $\epsilon=\delta t$ and $H$ as  our generating function. So, in this scenario, we end up with these equations

$$
    \delta q_i=\delta t[q_i,H]=\dot{q}_i\delta t~~~~~\delta p_i=\delta t[p_i,H]=\dot{p}_i\delta t.
$$

As a consequence
$$Q_i(t)=q_i(t)+\delta q_i(t)=q_i(t)+\dot{q}_i(t)\delta t=q_i(t+\delta t)$$
and
$$ P_i(t)=p_i(t)+\delta p_i(t)=p_i(t)+\dot{p}_i(t)\delta t=p_i(t+\delta t).$$

I have no difficulty understanding this concept. However, I would appreciate it if someone could provide an example of how we can use $H$ and $\delta t$ to derive the equations of motion.

Comment: Why the equations were edited? I'm new writing in the forum, maybe someone can tell me which is the correct format

Comment: Hi Manuel Borra. Welcome to Phys.SE. Be prepared that other users may edit your posts. I changed the notation $dt\to\delta t$ because this is the standard notation for an infinitesimal variation.

Comment: I have no problem with that, I was referring to the other equations, I noticed that they were edited (again I have no problem with that), but maybe I am not writing the equations in the best way.  And I would like to know which is the best way of writing equations.   Sorry if my previous message sounds like I am 
complaining, but as you might notice English is not my mother tongue so it is possible that i sound a bit rude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: It seems relevant in OP's context to mention that an infinitesimal time-evolution $\delta t=\epsilon$ of a [Hamiltonian system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics) can be modeled as an infinitesimal [canonical transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation#Type_2_generating_function) (ICT)
$$ (q^j,p_k)\quad\longrightarrow\quad(Q^j,P_k)$$
with a type 2 generating function
$$ F_2(q,P,t)=\sum_{j=1}^nq^jP_j +\epsilon H(q,P,t).$$

Comment: I do know that the ICTs are related to the generating function $F_2$ because this one gives us the identity transformation and  ICTs differ infinitesimally from them. All of that is clear, but I am looking forward to an example.  Something like  $H=p^2/2m$ and using the ICTs and the Hamiltonian I can know how the system evolves.

Comment: Hi Manuel Borra. Given what you already know, it seems it will be no problem for you to work out an example.

Answer (score 0):

If we take $H=p^2/2m+\kappa x^2/2$ then

$$\delta x=dt\bigg(\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}-\frac{\partial x}{\partial p}\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}\bigg)=\dot x dt$$
so
$$\dot x=p/m$$

doing the same with $\delta p$ we have $\dot p=-kx$ so finally taking the derivative of $\dot x=p/m$ we end up having

$$\ddot x=-\frac{\kappa}{m}x$$
and the solution is
$$x(t)=A\sin(\omega t+\phi)$$

so we end up having the same equations of motion as if we have resolved the problem in the Lagrangian way.